# Can application templates be used to modify splash screen only?

Tags: python, startup-file, template

I'm trying to modify only the splash screen via app templates, while maintaining the users prefs and startup for each user (studio environment). The documentation makes it seem possible as mentioned here:

```
"Template Contents

Each of the following files can be used for application templates but are optional.

startup.blend
Factory startup file to use for this template.

userpref.blend
Factory preferences file to use for this template. When omitted preferences are shared with the default Blender configuration.

(As noted previously, this is only used for a subset of preferences).

splash.png
Splash screen to override Blender’s default artwork (not including header text). Note, this image must be a 1000x500 image.

__init__.py
A Python script which must contain register and unregister functions."
```

In my case I was only supplying a splash.png and assuming it would pull from the users userprefs for everything else that is not supplied, however for everything else it seems to default to factory defaults. Its important to maintain each users preferences in this case as this is being distributed in a large studio environment. What would be my options here?